# Is it possible to silently install a local Chrome extension via the Windows registry?

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, registry

My extension has a connection to my native application via NativeMessage, and I would like to simplify the installation process.
We've considered uploading our extension to the Google Web Store, so Chrome will handle the process, but there is a problem. The manifest version of my extension is v2. Due to the Store's policy, extensions with v2 are no longer available to publish on the Store.
So we want to install it "manually," which means we 're using a native application (.net application) to complete the installation via the Windows registry after users click the "Install" button on our app.

We tried to write a registry like this:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\<extension_id>
path: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\myapp\extension.crx
version: 1.0
```

It doesn't work after restarting Chrome.

Any recommendations for me? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this is the reason your registry workaround is not working: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/ Note the warning section: "Windows and Mac installs must come from Chrome Web Store: As of Chrome 33, no external installs are allowed from a path to a local CRX file on Windows"